# Intermittent Error: Cross-Origin Request Blocked - CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing

Tags: node.js, express, cors, ibm-cloud

I have a simple REST API on ExpressJS deployed on Bluemix. I got the CORS error when trying to call that API from my AngularJS UI.

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at http://lh-mvp-api-dev.mybluemix.net/users. (Reason: CORS header ‘Access-Control-Allow-Origin’ missing)
```

So, based on other solutions around I added the cors package to my app.js as below:

```
var express = require('express'),  
app = express(),
port = process.env.PORT || 3000,
Temp = require('./app/models/tempModel'),
bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
cors = require('cors'); 

app.use(cors());
```

Now, it works fine intermittently and it doesn't work intermittently. On local it works always fine. On Bluemix it is intermittent. Even when it doesn't work if I repeat the action 3 or 4 times, it works the 4th or 5th time. Has anyone faced a similar issue with CORS intermittently? Any thoughts on where this is going wrong. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you seen the video at this URL:
https://www.codeschool.com/discuss/t/how-to-solve-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-present-on-the-requested-resource-origin-null-is-therefore-not-allowed-access-in-angular-js/28989

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This happened when the CORS dependency was not added in package.json. Once added, the error went away forever.

Answer (score 0):

This is normal situation in YOUR case .
1 solution
Download GOOGLE CHROME CORS extension [CORS EXTENSION](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi?hl=en)

2 solution use CORS webpack

npm install CORS --save (--save if you want to insall noted module only in currrent project)